# Java NIO server never finds any SelectionKey

Tags: java, server, client, nio

Using [this example](https://github.com/teocci/NioSocketCodeSample/blob/master/src/com/github/teocci/nio/socket/nio/NonBlockingWRServer.java) of a non-blocking NIO server, the non-blocking client is able to connect to the non-blocking NIO server. Even when the server stops running, the client repeats "broken pipe", which indicates that the client WAS connected. On the server-side, however, the `accept` `SelectionKey` is never "found" (i.e, in the loop, the `accept` method is never called). How is this possible? I even send requests to the server while the client is connected and the `read` and `write` methods aren't called either.

My code below is almost the same as the example:

SERVER

```
 package GameEngine;

import GameEngine.PlayerActions.PlayerAction;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.*;

import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;


/**
 * Receives input from clients
 */
public class InputReceiver extends Thread{ //  A separate thread.

    final String HOSTNAME = "localhost";
    final int PORT = 6666;
    private ServerSocketChannel serverChannel;
    private Selector selector;
    public static HashMap<String,ArrayList<PlayerAction>> inputsForNextTick = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<PlayerAction>>();
    private Map<SocketChannel, byte[]> dataTracking = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<SocketAddress,SocketChannel> clientSocketAddressToSocketChannel = new HashMap<>();
    private static boolean tickHappened = false;

    public static void notifyOfTick(){
        tickHappened = true;
    }


    public void run(){
            try {
                System.out.println("Registering server..");
                serverChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
                serverChannel.configureBlocking(false);
                serverChannel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(HOSTNAME, PORT));
                selector = Selector.open();
                serverChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
                System.out.println("Server registered.");
                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                    Iterator<SelectionKey> keys = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();

                    while (keys.hasNext()) {
                        System.out.println("Key found. Choosing operation.");
                        SelectionKey key = keys.next();
                        keys.remove();

                        if (!key.isValid()) {
                            continue;
                        }

                        if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                            System.out.println("Accepting connection");
                            accept(key);

                        }
                        if (key.isWritable()) {
                            System.out.println("Writing...");
                            write(key);
                        }

                        if (key.isReadable()) {
                            System.out.println("Reading..");
                            read(key);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

    private void accept(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
        ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel = (ServerSocketChannel) key.channel();
        SocketChannel socketChannel = serverSocketChannel.accept();
        socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
        byte[] hello = "Connection established.".getBytes();
        dataTracking.put(socketChannel, hello);
        socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
        clientSocketAddressToSocketChannel.put(socketChannel.getRemoteAddress(), socketChannel);
        System.out.println("New connection made from address: " + socketChannel.getRemoteAddress());

    }
    private void read(SelectionKey key){

    }
    private void write(SelectionKey key) throws IOException
    {
        SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();

        byte[] data = dataTracking.get(channel);
        dataTracking.remove(channel);
        channel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(data));
        key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);
    }
    private void writeToSocketAddress(){

    }

}
```

CLIENT

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.util.Iterator;

import static java.nio.channels.SelectionKey.OP_READ;
import static java.nio.channels.SelectionKey.OP_WRITE;
public class ClientToServerCommunications implements Runnable
{
    private final static String HOSTNAME = "127.0.0.1";
    private final static int PORT = 6666;

    private Selector selector;

    public ClientToServerCommunications()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        SocketChannel channel;
        try {
            selector = Selector.open();
            channel = SocketChannel.open();
            channel.configureBlocking(false);

            channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT);
            channel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(HOSTNAME, PORT));

            while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                //selector.select(1000);

                Iterator<SelectionKey> keys = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();

                while (keys.hasNext()) {
                    SelectionKey key = keys.next();
                    keys.remove();

                    if (!key.isValid()) continue;

                    if (key.isConnectable()) {
                        System.out.println("Connecting..");
                        connect(key);
                    }
                    if (key.isWritable()) {
                        write(key);
                    }
                    if (key.isReadable()) {
                        read(key);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            close();
        }
    }

    private void close()
    {
        try {
            selector.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void read(SelectionKey key) throws IOException
    {
        SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
        ByteBuffer readBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1000);
        readBuffer.clear();
        int length;
        try {
            length = channel.read(readBuffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Reading problem, closing connection");
            key.cancel();
            channel.close();
            return;
        }
        if (length == -1) {
            System.out.println("Nothing was read from server");
            channel.close();
            key.cancel();
            return;
        }
        readBuffer.flip();
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        readBuffer.get(buff, 0, length);
        System.out.println("Server said: " + new String(buff));
    }

    private void write(SelectionKey key) throws IOException
    {
        SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
        channel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap("TEST MESSAGE".getBytes()));

        // Lets get ready to read.
        key.interestOps(OP_READ);
    }

    private void connect(SelectionKey key) throws IOException
    {
        SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
        if (channel.isConnectionPending()) {
            channel.finishConnect();
        }
        channel.configureBlocking(false);
        channel.register(selector, OP_WRITE);
    }
}
```

Comment: @user16320675 yup that fixed it!

Comment: @user16320675 Hi would you mind with one more question? The server accepts the connection made and then writes to the client, saying "Connection established". For some reason though, the server attempts to write a second time. Since the array of `byte[] data` is null, the Thread throws an exception. How is that possible? It's like the first `write` key is never removed even though `key.remove` is called (I removed `key.interestOps(OP_READ)` in the `write` method. This is for sure the issue, since when I leave the `OP_read`, it just keeps reading an infinite number of times.

Comment: @user16320675 Where is the comment that is referred to here?